# JQuery Validator- Rule specific errorPlacement

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, errorplacement

I'm using jquery validator.

I've got a custom rule applied to a group of elements in my form. These inputs may also have other (standard) rules associated with them. I need to place the error message in one place if the element fails my custom rule, but another place if the element fails a standard rule.

I need something like -

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
    if (error == MyCustomError) {
        // put my error at the top of the form
    } else {
        // put my error next to the element
    }
```

I can't see what that 'error' object really is (tried drilling down with firebug but it wasn't very informative).

The highlight option is even more difficult because I don't even have the 'error' parameter to use.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

error is the whole error label HTML element that is being added by jQuery Validate, i.e.:

```
<label class="error">Error message here</label>
```

So if you want to place the message differently if the message is "Do not do this", you can:

```
errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
if (error.text() == "Do not do this") {
    error.insertBefore("SELECT FIRST ELEMENT IN THE FORM HERE USING STANDARD JQUERY SELECTORS");
} else {
    error.insertAfter(element);
}
```

Comment: This will only work if you are working with single language. Any idea how to get the rule type instead?

Comment: jQuery Validate doesn't provide the rule type by default in the errorPlacement method. But you have the *element*, so you can do:

`element.data('rule')` and assign the `data-rule="required"` for example straight on the element in your HTML. That way you can use that once you need to put the error messages. Let me know if that helps!

Comment: Thanks for getting back tome, @Smilyan. That sounds like a valid path to take. In my particular use case, I ended up creating hidden input with the jQuery validator data attributes injected by the controller, so on client side, I just added keyup event to modify value + trigger validation for that hidden input.

Comment: I personally have created a wrapper class around the whole jQuery validate. That way I can put on any form `.validate-form` class to start validating and then for each method that I wish I add a class on the input for example `.validate-min-length` with data-attributes `data-min-length="20"`. Then you can use those classes in your errorPlacement method and know that they are used for that (and you can have more than 1 validation method as well). That way I don't need to repeat code at all and just use classes for any new forms.